# How to change the font of an element by clicking on another element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a style guide generator that would allow someone to select a font they want to use in their project. It would have a list of fonts to choose from and then when they click on the font they would want it'll change the h1 tag so they can preview  the font selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple Snippet, that does what I think your after.

```js
const demo = document.querySelector("h1");

for (const a of document.querySelectorAll(".select-font"))
  a.onclick = () => {
    demo.style.fontFamily = a.style.fontFamily;
  }
```

```css
.select-font {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: silver;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>Click one of the fonts</div>

<div class="select-font"
  style="font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif">
Times</div>
<div class="select-font" 
  style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
Arial</div>
<div class="select-font" 
  style="font-family: 'Comic Sans MS', cursive, sans-serif">
Comic</div>


<br>
<h1>Demo</h1>
```

Comment: Thank You So much! I have one more question. If I wanted the fonts to change when the mouse hovers over a element would I use          
   a.onhover = () => {

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `font-family` css property.

From javascript you can set it like this:

```
document.getElementById("preview_element").style.fontFamily = "arial"
```